# Identifying a skin disease using image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I currently have 2 seperate data sets that belong to 2 different skin diseases. I have drawn an [abstract image differentiating the 2 diseases on MS Paint.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfqKg.png)[image] `Disease 1` tends to be rounder in shape than `Disease 2` and there is a texture difference as well.

Using texture filters and segmentation functions on Matlab, I am able to locate the disease region (and draw a border around it), for both `Disease 1` and `2`. My question is how can I differentiate between the 2 diseases? Are there functions I can use or am I better off using some form of machine learning on the data sets.

Any advice at all is helpful as I'm only starting out with Matlab.

Comment: I think this is the kind of question that only you could answer. You have to go through your data over and over and over again and look for features that are reliably different. You have to spend hours and hours looking ploughing through it. You have noticed that the texture is different. That is a good start. How are they different? How would you describe the difference if you were to describe it in words? How would you describe the difference if you were to write pseudo code? You can start looking into various algorithms, coding it up etc once you have those answers.

Comment: @kkuilla The prime different between the two diseases that I've identified is that `disease1` almost always appears in a circular shape, where as the shape of `disease 2` is random and may randomly take a circular shape. In terms of texture, `disease 1` has a white formation in the middle of the red patch. Can you suggest a place to start, an algorithm perhaps in terms of these characteristics alone? ie, shape, color and texture? (I have already played around with texture filters in Matlab.)

Comment: If you have enough data, you can always throw neural networks at such problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `regionprops` function to compute various shape features, like area, perimeter, eccentricity, etc. In particular, the eccentricity will tell you how close the shape is to a circle.

For texture features, try `extractHOGFeatures` and `extractLBPFeatures` functions in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say texture characterization:

1. Size Zone Matrix (really effective for homogeneity/heterogeneity description)
2. Haralick (cooccurrences matrix)
3. Run Length Matrix
4. Local Binary Pattern (extensively used nowadays).
5. Shape indexes to characterize the shape if according to your opinion the shape is relevant.

Then you use the classifier of your choice (Neural Network, SVM, etc).

An other solution, may be to use a Convolutional Neural Network, but that will require more work and data. But terribly efficient.

Comment: Thanks, are these texture characterization functions already available in Matlab or not?

Comment: Haralick for sure, and I guess that you will also find the LBP, and certainly the RLM. But I have a doubt for the SZM.

Comment: As say in an other post, for LBP: extractLBPFeatures