# How to plot the support vectors and test data for an SVM

Tags: matlab, svm

I am using Matlab for this simple image classifier.
I have two arrays of images, as follows:

```
DataSet = cell([], 1);
TestSet =  cell([], 1);
```

I am populating these arrays using a loop, as follows:

```
DataSet{j} = double(imresize(tempImage,[width height]));
```

Also, `train_label` is defined as follows, and helps separate the 2 categories:

```
train_label = zeros(size(10,1),1);
train_label(1:5,1) = 1;         % 1 = my first category of images
train_label(6:10,1) = 2;         % 2 = my second category of images
```

I am now training an SVM classifier as follows:

```
SVMvar = svmtrain(Training_Set , train_label, 'kernel_function', 'linear');
```

Now I am able to pass an image through this classifier and get an acceptable result using `svmclassify`.

My question is, how can I plot the test data (and support vectors) on a graph so that I can see how close they came to being classified into category 1 or 2?

I realize I used a linear kernel but most of the material I read indicate I need to plot a 3D graph. Why is it a 3D graph and not a 2D graph, and how can I do it?

Comment: You can only really plot them if the feature space is two (or three) dimensional. What do you use as your features?

Comment: PS: There is an [example in the docs](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) doing exactly what you want. [tag:rtfm]

Comment: @flawr Sorry but I have no idea what my features are. How do I check? Right now, training and classification is done with 100% accuracy (training data and test data are not the same). Also, I tried the example in the doc but when I add the `'ShowPlot',true` parameter, the line gives me an error.

Comment: Well what feature vectors exactly are you passing to the SVM? At the moment it seems you are just plugging the whole image in, this means a quite high dimensional space. (If it is a colour image, 3 dimensions per pixel.) It usually does not make very much sense to do this (Why would you expect to get a linear decision funciton in *this* space?), and it is obviously impossible to represent this in a plot.

Comment: I am not passing any feature vectors to my knowledge. I am only resizing the image and making it greyscale before putting it in. Is this incorrect? Inefficient? The reason I want to see a graph is I want to know how close my classifier came to incorrectly/correctly classifying a particular test image.

Comment: The grayscale values of all the pixels of an image combined form your feature vectors. But these values quite meaningless on general pictures. The first questions in pattern recognition tasks are always: What features have any significance in my classification process? How can I exctract those features from my data (in your case images)? And at the very end you decide what kind of classifier you want to use. 

So what kind of images are you using?

Comment: Let's say you have images of triangles and squares, and you want to classify which image shows a triangle, which one a square. The grayscale value of each pixel does really tell you nothing about whether there is a triangle or a square, so it does not make sence to plug those into your classifier. You probably first want to extract the number of corners of the shapes in your image, and use this number as a feature which you can pass to your classifier. (Which in this case is obviously trivial.)

Comment: Thanks for all that info. This previous question I asked will detail what I'm trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128967/identifying-a-skin-disease-using-image-processing Also, I'm surprised as to how I'm getting 100% accuracy rate right now. What can I do to improve my solution?

Comment: The reason I picked SVN over something like ANN is because I read that for smaller datasets, SVN's are better. Also, as described in my other question I'm planning on extracting information such as roundness (in a numerical form) for each lesion in an image. May I ask how these values can be plugged into an SVN using Matlab (I could not find a simple enough example for this). Do I create a vector manually with the roundness values and pass it in like I did above for the grayscale image?

Comment: I assume you do not have many more training examples than numbers of dimensions, so if you are only checking training images, this is no surprize. But I suspect the generalization performace would be quite bad.

Comment: `more training examples than numbers of dimensions`, what do you mean? My current training set contains about 10 images and the test set another 10 different images. But yes, these images look rather similar as they are from the same patient (different locations).

Comment: Yes, that would be a good approach: For each image, exctract some meaningful data: You said roundness, so you can perhaps use the mean curvature as one dimension, the standard deviation of the colour values as another dimension e.t.c. Note that you can also use nonlinear kernels, which can adapt to almost anything.

But for familiarizing yourself with the SVM I recommend making yourself some data sets that you can easily visualize (e.g. two normal distributed classes in 2d ) and play around with those.

Comment: Those images might look similar to you, but when you look at what the computer sees (the numbers of the gray values) you will not be able to tell any of those from the other one. Right now lets assume your have 200x200 pixel grascale images, that makes a 40000 dimensional feature space. That means even a simple *linear* decision function has 40001 degrees of freedom, that means you are overfitting.

Comment: I really recommend getting into some of the basics of pattern recognition first, before you dive int SVMs etc

Comment: So you're saying that each characteristic of an image (roundness, color gradient etc) is a dimension? Could you tell me why a simple linear decision function has 40001 degrees of freedom (if images are 200x200) and why it's overfitting?

Comment: It's alright, but why do you say it's overfitting?

Comment: I am not gonna explain anything further, as this lecture has already been beyond the scope of this site. Take a pattern recognition/machine learning class or get some books / read some WP articles.

Comment: It's cool, appreciate your effort. I know I'm finding my way in the dark here and this has given me some guidance. Thanks.